# html form won't get

Tags: html

I am using a html form to with a get method to submit information to another page

```
<form name="test" action="gallery.html" method="get">
    <div class="searchbar">
        <div class="tb-artist">
            <input id="artist" type="text" class="tb-artist-a" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="searchbutton" />
    </div>
</form>
```

It visits the gallery page but doesnt append on the information, why doesnt it just work

just figured it out, im using id instead of name

Comment: You figured it out but submitted the question anyway?

Comment: i figured it out 30 seconds after posting the question, edited it in and saw all the replies lol

Comment: Ah no problem then.  That's stumped me once too.  Took me an hour only to find out I was using id rather than name. Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a `name` to your input:

```
<input id="artist" name="artist" type="text" class="tb-artist-a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input id="artist" type="text" class="tb-artist-a" />` doesn't have a [**name**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT) so it cannot be a successful control.